# the values of a global variable changed, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have this code snippet that I don't know why the variables' value changed.

```
while (increment > 0) {
        for (i = increment; i < n; i++) {
            var unsorted = list;
            console.log(unsorted + " -> unsorted" + i);
            var temp = list[i];
            var j = i;
            while (j >= increment && list[j - increment] > temp) {
                list[j] = list[j - increment];
                j -= increment;
            }
            list[j] = temp;
            console.log(unsorted + " -> must not change" + i);
            console.log(list + "-> must not be the same below");
        }
 }
```

When i logged the variable `unsorted` again, the values have been changed? why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only ever have one array.

`var unsorted = list` creates a second reference that points to **the same** array instance.

Instead, you can call `list.slice()`, which returns a (shallow) copy of the array.